# How to install vimtrainer?

Tags: installation, vim, tar, ruby

I'm trying to install [vimtrainer](http://vimtrainer.sourceforge.net/).

First I did:

```
$ svn co https://vimtrainer.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/vimtrainer/trunk vimtrainer
$ cd vimtrainer
```

Then made sure `ruby`, `rubygems`, `rake` and `vim with +ruby` were installed.

Then under `Unpacking and installing` in `user_guide.txt` it says I should do `tar zxvf vimtrainer-?.?.?.tar.gz`.

Where should I do this? I tried `tar zxvf vimtrainer-0.0.1.tar.gz` but I get `Cannot open: No such file or directory`.

Comment: That would usually be for extracting the source code if you had downloaded it in an archive, a `.tar.gz` to be exact, which you did not. let me look closer

Comment: Thnx, [here](https://gist.github.com/4128852) you can find the vimtrainer tree and the contents of the `user_guide.txt`

Comment: Can you try just the last 2 instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, that makes for a nice and short beginner level tutorial:

1. **Search-based navigation**

   Because the problem is with `authors`, we have to search for the string `authors` in the rakefile. Vim's most basic search commands are `/` (forward search) and `?` (backward search.

   Let's start by opening `Rakefile` with Vim:

   ```
   $ vim Rakefile
   ```

   Then we search for `authors`:

   ```
   /authors<CR>
   ```

   `<CR>` is Vim's notation for the `Enter` key. Hmm, there's a problem: Vim can't find the string `authors`. Weird, let's try with `author`:

   ```
   /author<CR>
   ```

   Bingo!
2. **Basic editing commands**

   The problem is obviously a typo: `s:author` should be `s:authors`. That's an easy one.

   Because `/` left us on the first character of `author`, we must jump to the `e`nd of the word with:

   ```
   e
   ```

   Then we enter *insert* mode `a`fter the cursor, add the missing `s` and go back to *normal* mode:

   ```
   as<Esc>
   ```
3. **Saving and quitting**

   In Vim all the file management tasks are primarily done with "Ex commands" typed at the command line. From *normal* mode, hit `:` to enter "command line mode" and type the commands that you need. The command for saving your changes to the current buffer is `:write` or `:w`. Let's write the file:

   ```
   :w
   ```

   And quit:

   ```
   :q
   ```

   Or write the file *and* quit:

   ```
   :wq
   ```

After that, follow the instructions.

Note that this thing doesn't work on my Mac: it's complaining *at runtime* about some missing lib while it should complain about that at build time. Bad.

Comment: Thnx! I was able to install successfully but when I ran `vimtrainer-server --start` I got this: `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/vimtrainer-0.0.1/lib/vimtrainer.rb:55: undefined method 'today' for Date:Class (NoMethodError)`. Running `vimtrainer-client` returned `Error detected while processing command line:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'today' for Date:Class`.
I get there is something wrong with that indicated file but I don't know to what I should change it. Any ideas?

Comment: Similar errors here. My opinion is that it's a poorly written program not worth the hassle. `$ vimtutor` is enough for the basics and using Vim daily is enough to learn how to use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just the below instructions ?

> cd vimtrainer
>   rake gem
>   sudo gem install pkg/vimtrainer-?.?.?.gem

replace `vimtrainer-?.?.?.gem` with the name of the file that is created from `rake gem`

Comment: What `vimtrainer` dir do you mean, the top dir or the one in the `lib` dir? Doing `rake gem` from the top dir gets me this:
`rake aborted!
authors must be an Array of String instances
Tasks: TOP => gem => pkg/vimtrainer-0.0.1.gem`

Comment: I would have assumed top dir.. I need to look closer yet. Can you try from lib dir itself? i.e from `vimtrainer/lib/` What does Readme say? edit: readme is useless. It is still looking like top dir is the right place..

Comment: Im not at home so I cant try myself, but if nothing else is working can you try renaming `vimtrainer/Rakefile` line 72 from `s.author` to `s.authors` and try again?

Comment: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20 . Yup its looking like that is the typo thats causing the issue.